# Java - arrayList of Integer not initialize

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know how to initialize synapseNeuronList arrayList. got null error

```
private ArrayList <Integer> synapseNeuronList;
for (int j=1;j<strLine.split(" ").length-1;j++){                                              
synapseNeuronList.add(Integer.valueOf(strLine.split(" ")[j]));  
}
```

Comment: `private ArrayList <Integer> synapseNeuronList = new ArrayList<Integer>();` ...

Comment: By the way, you should store the result of your split() method call in a variable.  Otherwise you're calling it twice per loop, which is a big performance hit.  Also, are you sure you want those conditions in your for loop and not  for(int j=0;j<strs.length;j++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `synapseNeuronList` needs to be reference to some ArrayList (or its subtype) object. To create object use `new` operator like this

```
private ArrayList <Integer> synapseNeuronList = new ArrayList <Integer>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You would either do this directly when you declare the variable:

```
private ArrayList <Integer> synapseNeuronList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

or inside a constructor:

```
public YourClassConstructor() {
    synapseNeuronList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Hope this helps!